# Why Value is null for Custom Column for datagridview?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

i am binding a datatable to the datagridview with custom column.

here's my code for the custom column.

Note : There's no cell editing involved.

```
public class GridCustomColumnCell : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public GridCustomColumnCell() : base(new CustomCell())
    {

    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell. 
            if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a Special Cell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    private string strID;
    private string statusID;

    public CustomCell() : base()
    {
        string[] data = (string[])Value;
        if (data != null)
        {
            strID = data[0];
            statusID = data[1];
        }
    }

    private static readonly StringFormat strFmt = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, 
                                  Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, 
                                  DataGridViewElementStates cellState, 
                                  object value, object formattedValue, 
                                  string errorText, 
                                  DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
                                  DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, 
                                  DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, 
                   formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, 
                   paintParts);

        DataGridViewCellStyle cstyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        cstyle.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16, FontStyle.Bold);
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, cellBounds);
        graphics.DrawString(" \n\n", cellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, cellBounds);
        graphics.DrawString("  " + statusID + "", cstyle.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                            cellBounds);
        graphics.DrawString("\n\n\n  " + strID + "", cellStyle.Font, 
                            Brushes.Blue, cellBounds);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        ContextMenuStrip cs = new ContextMenuStrip();
        cs.Items.Add("Fsdfsfs ");
        //  cs.Items.Add()
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            cs.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.    
            return typeof(String[]);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value. 
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code for databinding:

```
try
{
    FrameFactory ff = new FrameFactory();
    ff.NewFrame("C:\\XMLsample\\s1.xml");

    GridCustomColumnCell cc = new GridCustomColumnCell();
    cc.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
    cc.DataPropertyName = "test";

    gridMain.Columns.Add(cc);
    gridMain.ReadOnly = true;
    this.gridMain.RowCount = 5;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.gridMain.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = new string[] { "1", "2" };
    }
    //DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    //dt.Columns.Add("test", Type.GetType("System.String").MakeArrayType());
    //DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    //dr[0] = new string[] { "1", "2" };
    //dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    //gridMain.DataSource = dt;

    //   dt.Row
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Even with datatable direct binding, the **value** is null under the **DataGridViewTextBoxCell**

Anyone can help me with the missing piece of code ?

Comment: Is the DataGridView's AutoGenerateColumns set to false? Is the  `DataPropertyName = "test"` correct? Why is: `cc.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;`?